# Bitwise multiplication with correction for overflow

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am trying to use Bitwise operators ( ! ~ & ^ | + << >>  ) in C to achieve a multiplication of 4 while also correcting for Positive and Negative overflow by returning the Max value and Minimum value, respectively.
For example,

```
Function(0x10000000) = 0x40000000
Function(0x20000000) = 0x7FFFFFFF
Function(0x80000000) = 0x80000000
```

My primary method is checking the sign of the product to find if it changed expectedly.

```
    int funcMultBy4(int x){
        int signedBit=(x>>31);                                                                            
        int minValue= 1<<31;
        int xtimes4= x<<2;
        int maxValue= (x ^ xtimes4) >> 31;
        int saturate= maxValue & (signedBit ^ ~minValue);
        return saturate | (xtimes4 ^ ~maxValue) ;
     }
```

Currently, when multiplying 0x7fffffff, I am getting -1 rather than an expected 0x7FFFFFFF. I understand there is probably a necessary shift by 1 somewhere, but am having trouble finding my error.

Comment: `!` and `+` are not bitwise operators. They're logical operators.

Comment: Just use `number << 2`. Remove the MSB and or it back in afterwards if you want signed numbers.

Comment: What is `mul4`?

Comment: @JL2210 I *think* its *supposed* to be `xtimes4`.

Comment: @JL2210, it was a mixed up value. It was supposed to be xtimes4

Comment: `signedBit` - we assume negative numbers use twos complement and that `sizeof(int)` is 4?

Comment: `1<<31` is _undefined behavior_ (UB) as is `x<<2;` for large `x`. In C, this restrictions of `! ~ & ^ | + << >>` will leads to UB looking for _overflow_.  Recommend   you try some assembly code instead.  If this is a class assignment, the curriculum is stuck in the 80s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the `^` in the last line that needs to be `&` and overflow must be detected in both the first and second bit-shift.

This slight reorganisation of the function seems more intuitive to me:

```
     int funcMultBy4(int x)
     {
        int signedBit = (x>>31);
        int minValue = 1<<31;
        int xtimes4 = x<<2;
        int overflow = (x ^ (x<<1) | (x ^ (x<<2))) >> 31;
        int saturate = (signedBit ^ ~minValue);
        return (overflow & saturate) | (~overflow & xtimes4) ;
     }
```

Of course, the code depends on the int size to be 32 bits. You may either use the fixed-width type `int32_t` or replace `31` by `((int)((sizeof(int)<<3)-1))` (could be defined in a macro).

Comment: Ah, I completely forgot about checking within the first shift as well. That makes sense and solves my problem. Thank you!